# Android Kitkat let other apps read files written to SDcard

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

What I am trying to do is the following:

- my app downloads a video (.mp4 file) from our fileserver and stores it on the SDCard (external strage)
- I want to play the video with the installed Video player

This works fine for Android 4.3:

```
String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                    + java.io.File.separator + RESPATHCONSTANT 
                    + java.io.File.separator + filename;

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
```

And then I fire the intent.

For Android 4.3 the Videoplayer takes over now and plays the video.

For Android 4.4 I am able to use a filebrowser, navigate to the video and then use the installed videoplayer to play the video. (the browser has set the appropriate flag, so it is able to browse directories created by other programs) But I am not able to use the method mentioned above. As far as I know from Android 4.4 onwards, applications are only able to read and write to directories on the sdcard, which were created by the application itself. And I'm running into that problem.

How can I store such files and give other programs the permission to read them?

Comment: "my app downloads a video (.mp4 file) from our fileserver and stores it on the SDCard" -- the code you are using has nothing to do with an "SDCard". Here are some blog posts outlining the differences between what the SDK terms [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was in another place. The generated URI was fine for Android versions below 4.4, but with Android 4.4 the URI was not prepared appropriately.

With

```
Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
```

the URI is of the type StringURI

`/storage/emulated/0/.<appname>/r.a4dd6417bd9936aebf3942a0001d33c3.mp4`

With

```
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(new File(path))
```

the URI is of the type HierarchicalURI

`file:///storage/emulated/0/.<appname>/r.a4dd6417bd9936aebf3942a0001d33c3.mp4`